# excel filtering off multiple references?

Tags: vba, excel

How can I set up vba code to allow user to type in several selections and then the accompanying list filters based on that input, reference cell?  I tried this but its only filtering the first selection.

I set it up as a worksheet script, so it only runs on that one sheet and set it up to only run when the user input cells (A1, A2) are updated.

I then tried getting the lists in columns C:D to filter, based on the values in A1 and A2.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'This line stops the worksheet updating on every change, it only updates when cell is touched
If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:B5")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

With Sheets("TestTab")

.Range("C1:D100").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=.Range("A1").Value, Field:=2, Criteria1:=.Range("A2").Value

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to filter a single column with what is in either cell A1 or A2:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    'This line stops the worksheet updating on every change, it only updates when cell is touched
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    With Sheets("TestTab")

        .Range("C3:D100").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=.Range("A1").Value, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=.Range("A2").Value

    End With

End Sub
```

If you are trying to filter column C on A1 and column D on A2:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'This line stops the worksheet updating on every change, it only updates when cell is touched
If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

With Sheets("Sheet1")

    .Range("C1:D100").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=.Range("A1").Value
    .Range("C1:D100").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=.Range("A2").Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: In the first response, what if I want to filter by A1 AND A2 (not OR).

Comment: How could I adjust this to have the input reference cells (A1 & A2) be on a main input sheet which then updates the filters on a separate sheet?

Same code?

Comment: Are you trying to filter out what's in A1 & A2, or see ONLY what's in A1 & A2?  Using the code above with xlOr will leave both what's in A1 & A2 in your data.  You would use xlAnd if you are trying to filter out A1 & A2.

Comment: To filter something on a different sheet, change the With statement.  Something like With Sheets("OtherSheet").  This code will go in the main sheet.

Comment: Alright!  It's pretty much working.  

They only remaining problem is that some of the list has the value * (asterisk) instead of a full name.  

I'm trying to make it so the user can just type in * (asterisk)  into the input cell, but the code doesn't seem to like that.  It selects everything on the filter.

The code is saying to filter by cell A1, and A1 has the input * (asterisk) .

Comment: Actually, it would be better if * asterisk was always ALSO selected, in addition to user inputs....
I'm trying to get something like this working but its err-ing out.
Criteria1:="~*"

Comment: Use this: .Range("C1:D100").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array(.Range("A1").Value, .Range("A2").Value, "*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues